# Postgres 10 pooling issue

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection-pooling, npgsql

I 'm using Postgres 10

And I would like to limit connections via pooling. I use this syntax:

```
"my conexion": "Host=myhost;
Port=5432;
Database=mydb;
Username=postgres;
Password=XXX;
Persist Security Info=True;
Pooling=true;
MinPoolSize=1;
MaxPoolSize=20;
ConnectionLifeTime=15",
```

After deploying app with this connection string, I have more processes than expected:

```
postgres=# select state, count(1) from  pg_stat_activity  group by state;
 state  | count 
--------+-------
        |     5
 active |     1
 idle   |    47
```

MaxPoolSize=20 , so in IDLE column I should have 20 max no?
What is wrong? Someone can help me?

Comment: Which programming language and pool are you using? How do you know those other connections are from your application?

Comment: Hello
thanks for your attention. Well the programming language is C# .NET
And the pool is npgsql
Then, I check with ps -aux command from unix shell and I can see idle conexion for 2 databases (that is normal) the pool have been deployed for both DB
ps -ef|grep postg | grep -v grep | wc -l
65

And they  (developpers) just told me that they see this error:
System.ArgumentException: 'Couldn't set connectionlifetime
Parameter name: connectionlifetime'

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple client processes connecting to this database? Because the Npgsql pooling setting only holds for that specific process (the pool is internal, in-process).

Comment: Hello
Process can be defined by Port=5432 and Database=mydb write?

Comment: I have this:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "db1": "Host=myhost;Port=5432;Database=db1;Username=user1;Password=XXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20",
    "db2": "Host=myhost;Port=5432;Database=db2;Username=user2;Password=XXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True"Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20
  }
And only this 2 database connects

Comment: Then I check from psql:

idle                | StoreBillbackRequestHangFire |    21
 idle                | BillbackRequestHangFire      |    52

This one BillbackRequestHangFire looks wrong, here is the conexion string:
"HangfireConnection": "Host=myhost;Port=5432;Database=BillbackRequestHangFire;Username=postgres;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20"

Comment: Lock at the other columns in pg_stat_activity to figure out where the connections are coming from.

Comment: Hello.

For example application_name and client_hostname ?

 state  |           datname            | application_name | client_hostname | count 
--------+------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------
 idle   | StoreBillbackRequestHangFire |                |                 |    43
 idle   | billback                     |                  |               |     2
 idle   | StoreBillbackRequest         |                |                 |     3
 idle   | BillbackRequestHangFire      |                  |                 |    22

Empty...

Comment: Hello.

The idle process in the server never destroyed. Is this a "normal" behavior of postgres db?

Comment: Hello

With this query: select datname, client_addr, count(1) from  pg_stat_activity  group by datname,client_addr;

I have this output:
datname;client_addr;count
BillbackRequestHangFire;10.50.34.41;22
billback;10.50.34.41;2
StoreBillbackRequestHangFire;10.50.34.41;22
BillbackRequestHangFire;172.19.19.137;22
StoreBillbackRequest;10.50.34.41;3
postgres;172.17.100.38;1
StoreBillbackRequestHangFire;172.19.19.59;20
StoreBillbackRequest;172.19.19.59;1

Comment: Seem to be OK,no? if we consider that pooling apply to the couple: IP/DB...I'll change pooling to max pool= 10 to see the new behavior

Comment: yes it's Ok, thanks for all your advises. I see that conexion are well ordered, by IP we can see the repartition. I change max pool size to 30 and I have this:
StoreBillbackRequestHangFire 10.50.34.41 26
StoreBillbackRequestHangFire 172.19.19.59 24
Many thanks and have a nice week end !